# if exists in sql within a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, exists

I am trying to execute the following query to check the records from the 4 tables and then calling a function,but i get an error near the brackets.It works fine if I use case,but exits when the first condition is met. I need to evaluate for all the tables in the 4 IF's:

```sql
select account_id,
        (
        if exists (select account_id from [dbo].[TEST_R6]) 
        Begin
        select  dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,strs,vis)  + space(1) + 'rr'
        End


if exists (select account_id from tbl_noR6) 
   begin
      select dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(2) + 'cc'
  end


if exists (select account_id from tbl_acct) 
   begin
                 select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(3) + 'pp'
   end

if exists (select account_id from test_con) 
   begin
                select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(4) + 'no'
   end

     )as value from CRS_PRODLINE
```

code works partially with case statement and gives output only for the first case is met and does not check for the others:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.A_NAME) 
        FROM TEST_DEL c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

SET @query = 'SELECT account_id, ' + @cols + '  from 
        (select   account_id,
                (case
                when exists (select  account_id from [dbo].[TEST_R6]) 
                then 
                dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis)  + space(1) 


                when exists (select account_id from tbl_noR6) 
                then 
                dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(2)

                when exists (select account_id from tbl_acct) 
                then 
                dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(2)

            end) as value,
            assay_name
            from CRS_PRODLINE
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
            MAX(newvalue)
            for a_name in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: Query you written above is wrong. could you provide your usecase what exactly you want to achieve. give example

Comment: This dint help, this is already part of dynamic query where I to pivot the the data obtained from these tables. What I actually need is just to call the function with the specified spaces depending on the tables that it is present in. eg if the account is present in 1st table then the function should give its output with 1 space, if in 2nd table with 2 spaces and so on! I am adding the code that works partially with case statement, but as is the case with sql select it falls out as soon as the first condition is met!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there is any record in the table your exists clause will return true.  I will assume that this is intentional and you are not trying to match on a specific account_id.

If you want to use this structure you will have to use dynamic SQL.  Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000)
IF EXISTS (SELECT account_id FROM tbl_noR6)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'select dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(2) + ''cc'''
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ')as value from CRS_PRODLINE'
    EXEC @Sql
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT account_id FROM tbl_acct)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(3) + ''pp'''
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ')as value from CRS_PRODLINE'
    EXEC @Sql
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT account_id FROM test_con)
BEGIN
    SET @Sql = 'select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(4) + ''no'''
    SET @Sql = @Sql + ')as value from CRS_PRODLINE'
    EXEC @Sql
END
```

Comment: This dint help, this is already part of dynamic query where I to pivot the the data obtained from these tables. What I actually need is just to call the function with the specified spaces depending on the tables that it is present in. eg if the account is present in 1st table then the function should give its output with 1 space, if in 2nd table with 2 spaces and so on! I am adding the code that works partially with case statement, but as is the case with sql select it falls out as soon as the first condition is met!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that CASE only evaluates once being a problem, this should build a string of all the applicable cases.

```
select account_id,
(
    '' 
    +
    case when exists (select account_id from dbo.[TEST_R6]) THEN select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,strs,vis)  + space(1) + 'rr' ELSE '' END
    +
    case when exists (select account_id from dbo.tbl_noR6) THEN select dbo.make_indicator(acent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(2) + 'cc' ELSE '' END
    +
    case when exists (select account_id from dbo.tbl_acct) THEN select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(3) + 'pp' ELSE '' END
    +
    case when exists (select account_id from dbo.test_con) THEN select dbo.make_indicator(cent,chem,co,dim,lg,pl,str,vis) + space(4) + 'no' ELSE '' END    
 ) as value

from CRS_PRODLINE
```